# ASP.NET Entity Framework determine if context saved successfully

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity, savechanges

I'm having a discussion with a friend about how to check if the context was saved successfully in Entity Framework.

His opinion is that we should check the integer returned by `SaveChanges()` and compare it to what we expected
Example: [Check expected with returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf3lc.png)

Mine is that we can assume that `SaveChanges()` did it's job and everything was saved to the database if no exceptions are thrown.
Example: [Catch exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xzeG.png)

I found two similar question here, but they don't explain much.
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331017/check-if-insertss-or-updates-was-successful-in-entity-framework)
[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263973/ef4-3-know-if-context-has-successfully-inserted-entity)
**So which method is better, and why?**

Comment: Why not use both?

Comment: actually, when SaveChanges() does not throw an exception, the statement executed successfully. The other possibility is valid, however it is already used internally (inside SaveChanges()), which would cause a DbUpdateConcurrencyException or DbUpdateException (when ExecuteNonQuery, i.e. the to be return value of SaveChanges, is not what is expected), otherwise a DbEntityCommandException (or something along those lines) when the query could not be transmitted/there was a SqlException while executing.